# MVC - Send HtmlHelper object by controller Content (function) argument?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way to return HtmlHelper object from controller to view?

In code:

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult SomeFunc(int id)
    {
        if (condition)
            return Content();//here i would like to send Html.ActionLink("Text", "Action")
        else
            return Content();
    }
```

The link will get handle in **javascript:**

```
        $.get("", { id: $("#id").val() }).
    done(function (data) {
        if (data != 0) {
            $("#someDOMID").val(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: the most easier it's creating a partial view and consume from client side via Ajax, but I think it is possible to use helper in action method and return html from there.

Comment: there is need for server logic to deside which link to generate

Comment: partial view can have this code embedded, or put it in controller and pass ViewBag or model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to send a link as mentioned in your question then try this:

```
public ActionResult GetLink()
{
    string url = Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id = 1 });
    return Content(url);
}
```

Otherwise, it's better to use the Partial View approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the content to contain a raw html string then you can create a function to render a partial to a string serverside and return that.

You could then take it another step and create a generic `ActionLinkPartial` that contained one embedded `@Html.ActionLink` and accepted a model that had your action link configuration settings.

Something like...

```
   protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        ViewData.Model = model;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

And use a model like...

```
public class ActionLinkModel
{
   public string Text{get;set}
   public string Action{get;set;}
}
```

Invoke it like...

```
var html = this.RenderPartialViewToString("Partials/Html/ActionLinkPartial", model);
```